# JBoss Developer Studio IDE not refreshing files

Tags: java, svn, jboss, tortoisesvn, auto-versioning

I have JBoss Developer Studio 7 as part of JBoss EAP 6.4. I have svn project opened in JBoss Developer Studio. Externally I am updating svn files using Tortoise SVN Client. Although even after F5 (Refresh) JBoss IDE (JBoss Developer Studio), sometime not reflecting the files properly.

Please advise. Is it not the good practice that I shouldn't update my svn files using Tortoise SVN Client.

Or I should follow some basic practice always while work with JBoss Developer Studio IDE. For now I cannot afford going for any JBoss SVN Client in the IDE due to my project constraints.

Thanks for any good suggestions.

Comment: Go to preferences -> Search for Workspace -> Refresh using native hooks and also try deleting the IDE generated folders in workspace this will solve problems with SVN.

Comment: I can delete `.settings` folder as many projects wrapped in. I can delete this off as it is not needed. Although afterwards `.svn` appears in the ide once I deleted `.settings` folder. Will it be bothersome. Else by ignoring this `.svn`, my ide will be functional by Refresh `F5`, I yet check for this part. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: I am not asking you to delete the .svn folder, I am saying IDE generated directories, sorry for confusion :) I am talking about these :  .DS_Store
 .metadata
.recommenders
RemoteSystemsTempFiles
 Servers

Comment: `(preferences)`->`General`->`Workspace`,- there I found the option `Refresh using native hooks or Polling` which is unset now. I made it to set by clicking the radio button. Let me observe that it solves the problem. I do not know why `.svn` had started appearing, it is a hidden folder.

Comment: `.settings` is project specific. Sorry for my confusion. Workspace has only `.metadata` folder in my case,- which has some information like `.plugins` folder. And series of `.bak_0`,`.bak_1`.., files. `.plugins` might be needed one. Let me wipe text files `.bak_0`,`.bak_1` and see how it goes. However I will do this as a secondary option. I hope the setting which you told should fine enough. Thanks. :)